# Generating packets in C

Tags: c

I am not receiving anything in buffer. Wherever I `printf` my buffer, it is always empty or shows garbage value. Can anyone help?

I defined header, packet and called them in my main, but buffer still shows garbage.

```
#include <stdint.h>
struct header {
    uint16_t f1;
    uint16_t f2;
    uint32_t f3;
};
struct data {
    uint16_t pf1;
    uint64_t pf2;
};
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "packet.h"
void htonHeader(struct header h, char buffer[8]) {
    uint16_t u16;
    uint32_t u32;
    u16 = htons(h.f1);
    memcpy(buffer+0, &u16, 2);
    printf("Value of buff is: %hu\n",buffer);
    u16 = htons(h.f2);
    memcpy(buffer+2, &u16, 2);
    u32 = htonl(h.f3);
    memcpy(buffer+4, &u32, 4);
}
void htonData(struct data d, char buffer[10]) {
    uint16_t u16;
    uint32_t u32;
    u16 = htons(d.pf1);
    memcpy(buffer+0, &u16, 2);
    u32 = htonl(d.pf2>>32);
    memcpy(buffer+2, &u32, 4);
    u32 = htonl(d.pf2);
    memcpy(buffer+6,&u32, 4);
}
void HeaderData(struct header h, struct data d, char buffer[18]) {
    htonHeader(h, buffer+0);
    htonData(d, buffer+8);
    printf("buff is: %s\n",buffer);
}
#include <stdio.h>
#include "packet.c"
#include <string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){ 
    struct header h;
    struct data d;
    char buff[18];
    //printf("Packet is: %s\n",buff);
    printf("Generating Packets..... \n"); 
        h.f1=1;
    d.pf1=2;
    h.f2=3;
    d.pf2=4;
        h.f3=5;
        HeaderData(h,d,buff);
    strcat(buff,buff+8);
    printf("Packet is: %s\n",buff);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen? You are writing to the buffer in unsigned integers and then reading back as a string.

Comment: I am trying to store packet in buffer.... the fields of packet has given a value in main. which is then saved to buffer in function HeaderData().
I want to save my whole packet, header along with data in buffer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `printf()`s are either syntactically wrong (`printf( "%hu", ... );` expects an unsigned short as parameter, but you pass a pointer) or you try to print `buff` by using `"%s"` but the content is binary, not text. What you could do instead was doing some kind of hexdump, like:

```
 int i;
 for( i=0; i<sizeof( buff ); i++ ) {
      printf( "%x ", buff[i] & 0xff );
 }
 puts( "" );  // terminate the line
```

Please note, that using `sizeof` works im `main()` only, in the other function you've got to determine the buffer size differently.

Besides: because of the binary content of `buff`, you can't use `strcat()`. Even if you have made sure that there is a `'\0'` behind the last value you have copied (I haven't checked if you have), depending on the integer values you copy, there may be another `'\0'` value before that one and `strcat()` would overwrite everything form that point on.

Comment: why not , if `buff` contains binary data; e.g. 6f 0 is the first short value (should be 28416 dec.)

Comment: how to display this data in decimal?

Comment: to do this you have to do what you hve done the other way round: `memcpy()` a part of `buff` into an integer type, convert it to host byte order and print it. You can't print the whole buffer decimally, except byte by byte.